# How to use template class as a template parameter for another class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have two classes, `A`, `B`, as given below

```
template <class T, int N> class A {
  public:
    /*some methods on the data*/
  private:
    T data_[N];
};

template <class T> class B {
  public:
    /*some methods on the data*/
  private:
    T data_;
};
```

Class `B` template arguments can only be some template specialization of class `A`. For example:

```
A<double, 4> a;
B<A<double, 4>> b;
```

I want the template parameter of class `B` to be some form of class `A` so that the code is more readable in terms of relation between `A` and `B`. I am not quite sure how to achieve that and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could just take `T` and `N` as class template arguments and declare `B::data_;` as being of type `A<T, N>` instead of type `T`, and then you would have `B<double, 4>` instead of `B<A<double, 4>>`. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: That would work, but I was wondering if there was any way that I could pass A as the template parameter instead.

Comment: `template< template<typename, int> typename T> class B {`

Comment: @Frank But that'll accept anything that accepts exactly a typename and an `int` as its template parameters, not just instantiations of `A`. And it _won't_ allow you to write `B<A<double, 4>> b;` because `A<double, 4>` isn't a template, it's a class.

Answer (score 2):

If the template `B` only uses the template `A`, then there is no reason to parametrise it. Instead, you could accept the parameters that you would use to instantiate the `A`:

```
template <class T, int N>
struct B {
    /*some methods on the data*/
  private:
    A<T, N> data_;
};
```

Comment: Consider a scenario when class `B` uses more template parameters than class `A`. How could one declare the template signature for class `B` in such a way that one can readily see that class `A` is one of the template parameters?

Comment: @bhache `how could one declare the template signature for class B in such a way that one can readily see that class A is one of the template parameters?` A isn't, and doesn't need to be a template parameter, thus it cannot and doesn't need to be seen. B simply has a member of type `A<T, N>` as can readily be seen from the member definitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the class A as default template template parameter of class B. Then you can declare `B<double,4>`. In the other words, if you want another class other than A e.g class C. You also can use `B<double,4,C>`

```
template <typename T, int N, template <typename, int> typename F = A> class B {
  public:
    /*some methods on the data*/
  private:
    F<T, N> data_;
};
```